# URL decode in Razor .NET file (cshtml)

Tags: c#, .net, razor

I'm POSTing url encoded data to a cshtml file. 
How can I decode the variables `customerEmail` and `customerRequest` before I email it?

```
@{
    var customerEmail = Request["customerEmail"]; 
    var customerRequest = Request["customerRequest"];

    var errorMessage = "";
    var debuggingFlag = false;
    try {
        // Initialize WebMail helper
        WebMail.SmtpServer = "your-SMTP-host";
        WebMail.SmtpPort = 25;
        WebMail.UserName = "your-user-name-here";
        WebMail.Password = "your-account-password";
        WebMail.From = "your-email-address-here";

        // Send email
        WebMail.Send(to: customerEmail,
            subject: "Dashboard Feedback from - " + customerEmail,
            body: customerRequest
        );
    }
    catch (Exception ex ) {
        errorMessage = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Decode"? Are they "foo%40bar.com"?

Comment: I'm not sure that sending email in cshtml is good idea, it's view and it's not related with sending email.

Comment: @DanielGrankin, this is not MVC,I think he is using WebMatrix.

Comment: @BradChristie, correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't.

The `Request` object decodes everything for you already.

Answer (score 6):

Using `System.Web.dll` you can decode information: [`HttpUtility.UrlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Example:

```
String foo = "foo%40bar.com";
String bar = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(foo);
// bar = "foo@bar.com"
```

But I should mention, incoming information should already be decoded through the `Request` object.